# Fluid simulation diffrent in 2.9

Tags: fluid-simulation

I just tried blender 2.9 and 2.9.1 and the fluid simulation is behaving differently from 2.8.3. I tried a simulation that splashes around a lot in 2.8.3. In 2.9 it just hits the ground, spreads and splashes up the domain sides a few minimally. The weird part is that the splashes stay the same, no matter the height of the emitter. How do I get it to splash more? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

They seem to have changed the time scale: 1 in 2.9.1 looks like .5 in 2.8.3. But that doesn't fix it.

water.blend in 2.8.3:
settings:

resolution devisions: 64
time scale: 0.5
timesteps max/min: 4/1
[image: screenshot 2.8.3]

water.blend in 2.9.1:
settings:

resolution devisions: 64
time scale: 1
timesteps max/min: 4/1[image]

Comment: Hi there Can you add some images of what is happening?Thank u

Comment: ok, here they are.   btw: How can I add a clip of the animation into the post?

Comment: Convert it into gif or record a gif under 2mb

Comment: ahh... thanks!!